# Long-Lived … how many pronounce it with a long "i"?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pronunciation of “Short-lived”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/pronunciation-of-short-lived)

I have read in Beastly Mispronunciations that long-lived is pronounced with a long "i." Does anyone actually pronounce it that way?

Answer (score 4):

There's a good discussion of this in the definition provided [at YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/long-lived):

> Some uncertainty exists as to the
>   correct pronunciation of *long-lived.*

According to their analysis, the reason both pronunciations (long and short 'i' forms) exist is that whereas the "live" part originally stemmed from the noun "life" (long 'i') it semantically drifted toward being perceived as originating from the verb "live" (short 'i').

Thus, while the long-i form may be technically correct, I can attest to never having heard it spoken that way - and if I ever did hear it, it would sound wrong to me.

Comment: I second this. [link]()